# PG::Error: ERROR: operator does not exist: double precision = boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have the following query executed in rails using find_by_sql

```
select LEAST(a,b) as min_value ,
CASE LEAST(a,b) 
WHEN LEAST(a,b) < 1.0 
then 1.0 
ELSE 1-LEAST(a,b) 
END 
from model where type=abc
```

but i am getting error as PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: double precision = boolean

I do not know what i am doing wrong. I just used this syntax from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: `type=abc` is the culprit i guess. What is `abc` ?

Comment: type may be some other text. abc is just a sample. I want to fetch the records based on type.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your CASE:

```
CASE LEAST(a,b) 
WHEN LEAST(a,b) < 1.0 then 1.0 
ELSE 1-LEAST(a,b) 
END
```

That form of [CASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) is going to try to compare `least(a, b)` (presumably a double precision value) with each of the WHEN expressions to see which one matches. You have only one WHEN:

```
WHEN LEAST(a, b) < 1.0
```

and that is a boolean so you're trying to compare a double precision value (`least(a, b)`) with a boolean (`least(a, b) < 1.0`) and PostgreSQL says no.

You probably want the other form of CASE:

```
case
when least(a, b) < 1.0 then 1.0
else 1 - least(a, b)
end
```

Comment: Is this is possible "@val = Model.find_by_sql("select 
CASE  
WHEN LEAST(a,b) < 1.0 
then 1.0 
ELSE 1-LEAST(a,b) 
END 
from model where type=abc")" if possible then how can i get the array of values?

Comment: What values? If you want functional `Model` instances then throw a `models.*` in the SELECT, you probably also want to give your CASE expression an alias so that you can refer to it in the objects.

Comment: I need to find the sum of the array in the same query. Take for example the previous query should return me something like [1.0, 0.9, 1.0, 1.0, 0.7] then i want to sum those values. How can i do this?

Comment: I'm only getting bits and pieces of what you're trying to accomplish, you might have better luck if you update your question.